# Resizing a game in browser

Tags: javascript, resize, scale, phaser-framework

I have problem with resize windows game. I've read various posts on the forum but I could not get the correct resize the view of the game.

If you rotate the device screen size, I would like to display the game has adapted to the width / height of the display device both horizontally and vertically.
When the game started, it is properly scaled up, just turning your exchange device scaling is incorrect. Return to the previous screen orientation device retains its proportions.

In template html I add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

First script:

```js
function preload() {
 ...
 Global.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;              
 Global.game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;                   
 Global.game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
 Global.game.scale.forceOrientation(true, false);
 Global.game.scale.setMaximum();
 Global.game.scale.setScreenSize(true);
 ...
}

function resize() {
 Global.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
 Global.game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
 Global.game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
 Global.game.scale.forceOrientation(true, true);
 Global.game.scale.setShowAll();
 Global.game.scale.refresh();
}
```

When I use this code, game scale correct when game started. When in device:

- change position with horizontal on vertical, game is bigges and show
  scroll
- change position with vertical on horizontal, game is flat

Second script:

```js
function preload() {
...
Global.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
Global.game.scale.parentIsWindow = true;
...
}
 
 
function resize () {
Global.game.scale.refresh();
}
```

When I use this code, game scale correct when game started. When in device:
1. change position with horizontal on vertical, game is scaled but on left and right is see white background
2. change position with vertical on horizontal, game is scaled but on bottom I see white background

I use Phaser 2.3

Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Thank you =)

**BEST SOLUTION**

Phaser 2.3 have a bug - not change resize site. I download 2.4.3 version.

I've added features that is loaded at the beginning, which guards the resolution change

```
    var attacks.base.x = 110;
    var attacks.base.y = 190;

    $(document).ready(function () {
       handleScreenResize(); 
    });

function handleScreenResize() {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
            timeoutResize = setTimeout(function () {
            var xButtonBase;
            var yButtonBase;

            /* resize game */
            game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
            game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
            game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
            game.scale.forceLandscape = true;
            game.scale.parentIsWindow = true;
            game.scale.refresh();

            /* get new width and height*/
            var gameWidth = game.width < game.world.width ? game.width : game.world.width;

            /** If you have static button you have change position use "cameraOffset.x" and "cameraOffset.y" set new position*/
            /* change position buttons attack */
            if(settings.control_option === 'RIGHTHAND') {
                xButtonBase = attacks.base.x;
                yButtonBase = game.height - attacks.base.y;
            } else {
                xButtonBase = gameWidth - attacks.base.x;
                yButtonBase = game.height - attacks.base.y;
            }

            /** set position buttons with attack and assist (down screen)*/
            attacks.base.button.cameraOffset.x = xButtonBase;
            attacks.base.button.cameraOffset.y = yButtonBase;

            }, 1000);
        });
    }
```

In preload add this script

```
 function preload() {
    ...
    Global.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
    Global.game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    Global.game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    Global.game.scale.forceLandscape = true;
    Global.game.scale.parentIsWindow = true;
    Global.game.scale.refresh();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue that my friend and I were getting when we were trying to re-size our game to a larger resolution if our window changed size.

See this issue: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1881
It should be fixed in Phaser 2.4 (RC1 is out now).

Comment: Did my suggestion fix your issue by any chance？

Comment: In 2.3 version I try different combinations but got no satisfactory result. If I find something I'll write.

Comment: Well as I said, it should be fixed in Phaser version 2.4. Try using that.

Comment: Pandacoder: Can I ask you to write me this piece of code responsible for scaling? I used this to my above. I also tried the Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE but did not work for me as I turn device.